# RSelenium, press a button based on string of text

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I'm collecting some data from a website and I need to press a button to print (and save) each object. To do so I use RSelenium. What I want to navigate to and click is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="clickAndTouch: onClick, blockTouches: true"><span data-bind="attr: { 'class': css() || name() }" aria-hidden="true" class="pri pri-print"></span><em data-bind="text: title()">Print</em></a>
```

I have tried several ways to navigate to this, I used the XPath, but the XPath changes for different searches. Since I want to automate this and collect more data this won't work. I believe that navigating and clicking by the text 'Print'' would be the most sufficient way. However, I've not found a proper way to do so. I tried:

```
remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', ("//*[text() = 'Print']"))$clickElement()
```

but that leads to this error:

```
Selenium message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.92)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: ElementNotVisible
     Detail: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I've also tried to go by class without any success. I'm relatively new to using Selenium so hopefully, someone can give me a solution and point out a better way to think about these issues when meeting them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's difficult to give a full working answer without having an actual URL to work with. However, it looks like you need to adjust your xpath to reach the `<a>` node in which the `<em>` node is embedded. You should be able to click that. Try  the following xpath : `"//a[em[contains(text(), 'Print')]]"`

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, that worked! Makes sense, thanks for explaining!